# In PHP, getenv('X') returns value that doesn't appear in getenv()

Tags: php

Running PHP 7.2.34 on a shared server. I have no control over the server, Apache, or PHP.

I set an environment variable in .htaccess like this:

```
SetEnv HOME /home/rochkind
```

getenv("HOME") returns the right string. But HOME doesn't appear in the getenv() array nor in the Environment section of phpinfo().

I have a theory, which is that getenv("HOME") and getenv() are not really accessing the same data. Perhaps the former is accessing Apache's idea of the environment, and getenv() and phpinfo() are going straight to the underlying OS.

Your idea?

Comment: Not the same as not using .htaccess but https://3v4l.org/nOSoe

Answer (score -1):

Environment support in PHP is not always obvious because it varies wildly depending on operating system and SAPI. In your case, you may want to try [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Unfortunately, it merges values from several sources, so you'll see your environment variables together with some web server variables and HTTP request headers:

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

```
array(38) {
  ["HOME"]=>
  string(14) "/home/rochkind"
  ["HTTP_HOST"]=>
  string(3) "example.com"
  ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
  string(78) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
  string(74) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
[...]
  ["windir"]=>
  string(10) "C:\WINDOWS"
  ["AP_PARENT_PID"]=>
  string(4) "4012"
}
```

Comment: Yes, HOME does show up in $_SERVER and in $_SERVER as reported by phpinfo(). Thanks for this tip. My question as to why getenv('HOME') returns a value not in the getenv() array is still out there, however. Also of note is that you can't look at the contents of $_SERVER to find the more complete environment, because the elements there (e.g., HOME) aren't identified as to how they got there. That is, it's not clear which elements came from the environment.